# Is there a HTTP gateway / HTTP server which can act as an FTP reverse proxy

Tags: http, ftp

I'm looking for a way to translate HTTP requests into FTP requests using a software gateway.

FTP is a really old protocol which has not aged well (personal opinion).  It is difficult to use with modern firewalls and securing it with TLS has significant pitfalls.
Yet Occasionally we find ourselves needing to access FTP servers for reasons we can't avoid.

The simplest solution to this might be to setup an HTTP server acting as a sort of reverse proxy to the FTP server:

- passing through http "basic auth" credentials to the FTP login
- At least supporting downloading a file
- ideally supporting upload as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Delegate proxy software](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/) and make it act as translator between HTTP and FTP. For more information you may check [this page](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/Manual.htm?DGproxy).

> DeleGate with RELAY="delegate" provides a special proxying without
> changing "proxy configuration" in browsers. When the URL of such
> DeleGate is http://delegate/, a user can access target URL via the
> DeleGate by giving a URL like http://delegate/-_-URL to the browser.